# How to scrape embedded integers on a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the number of likes for the datasets available on [this](https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset) website.

I've been unable to workout a way of reliably identifying and scraping the relationship between the dataset title and the like integer:

[image]

as it is embedded in the HTML as below:

[image]

I have used a scraper previously to get information about the resource urls. In that case I was able to capture the last child `a` of parent `h3` with a parent having class `.dataset-item`.

I would like to adapt my existing code to scrape the number of likes for each resource in the catalogue, rather than the URLs. Below is the code for the url scraper I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlparse

json_api_links = []
data_sets = []

def get_links(s, url, css_selector):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    base = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=urlparse(url))
    links = [base + item['href'] if item['href'][0] == '/' else item['href'] for item in soup.select(css_selector)]
    return links

results = []
#debug = []
with requests.Session() as s:

    for page in range(1,2):  #set number of pages

        links = get_links(s, 'https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset?page={}'.format(page), '.dataset-item h3 a:last-child')

        for link in links:
            data = get_links(s, link, '[href*="/api/3/action/package_show?id="]')
            json_api_links.append(data)
            #debug.append((link, data))
    resources = list(set([item.replace('opendata','') for sublist in json_api_links for item in sublist])) #can just leave as set

    for link in resources:
        try:
            r = s.get(link).json()  #entire package info
            data_sets.append(r)
            title = r['result']['title'] #certain items

            if 'resources' in r['result']:
                urls = ' , '.join([item['url'] for item in r['result']['resources']])
            else:
                urls = 'N/A'
        except:
            title = 'N/A'
            urls = 'N/A'
        results.append((title, urls))

    with open('data.csv','w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['Title','Resource Url'])
        for row in results:
            w.writerow(row)
```

My desired output would appear like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following.

I am using a css selector with Or syntax to retrieve title and likes as one list (as every publication has both). I then use slicing to separate titles from likes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv

def get_titles_and_likes(s, url, css_selector):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    info = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select(css_selector)]
    titles = info[::2]
    likes = info[1::2]
    return list(zip(titles,likes))

results = []

with requests.Session() as s:

    for page in range(1,10):  #set number of pages
        data = get_titles_and_likes(s, 'https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset?page={}'.format(page), '.dataset-heading .searchpartnership-url-analytics, .dataset-heading [href*="/data/dataset"], .dataset-item  #likes-count')
        results.append(data)

results = [i for item in results for i in item]

with open(r'data.csv','w', newline='') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerow(['Title','Likes'])
        for row in results:
            w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach is pretty straight forward. Your given website contains required elements in a list Tag. And what you need to do, is to get source code of that `<li>` tag, and just fetch Heading, which has a certain class and Same goes for like count.

The catch in like count is, the text comprises of some noise. To fix that, you can use regular expression to extract digits ('\d+') from given input of likes count. Following code gives desired result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

source = requests.get('https://data.nsw.gov.au/data/dataset')
sp = soup(source.text,'lxml')

element = sp.find_all('li',{'class':"dataset-item"})

heading = []
likeList = []
for i in element:
    try:
        header = i.find('a',{'class':"searchpartnership-url-analytics"})
        heading.append(header.text)
    except:
        header = i.find('a')
        heading.append(header.text)



    like = i.find('span',{'id':'likes-count'})
    likeList.append(re.findall('\d+',like.text)[0])




dict = {'Title': heading, 'Likes': likeList} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict,index=False) 
print(df)
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I get [this](https://imgur.com/undefined) error. I'm not familiar with Pandas yet so I don't quite understand the issue. Would appreciate any guidance on the error :)

Comment: Link is broken @krazykrejza . Try sending stack trace or screenshot again. And as of pandas, you can try another method as well there is no compulsion. Your Required heading and likes are already in heading list and likeList. You can do whatever you please.

Comment: Remove index=False in second last line. And it works flawlessly.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. What's the best way of getting it to loop through the entire catalogue? (~175 pages) Straight after this I'm going to have a good read the the Requests documentation to get my head around this stuff.